# How to make a selected area with a circular border?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, cs5, marquee-tool

I'm using Photoshop CS5

My question has two parts to it:

## 1

How can I make a circular selected area with a blank border (no fill) border (stroke: 30px)?

I'm going for a similar effect as produced by the Horizontal Type Mask Tool, just, instead of text, I would want to use the circular border as the mask.

## 2

After making a selection area I want to force that selection to do something with my photo like as if you are writing on in sand. (sand text)

To do that,  I copy and paste that selection but when I used blending options on my photo layer it seems there is a nub in my photo instead of a notch.

How can I do this job done right?
Sorry for my language ...
Best regards, thanks for future answers

Comment: I'm having a lot of trouble understanding your exact question, I'm sorry.

Comment: If you have an example picture of what you mean by number 2, that would be much appreciated.

Comment: "there is nub in photo instead notch" -- I don't understand this part, I'm sorry.

Comment: I _think_ he means to reproduce the effect of when you run your finger through the sand. He's probably doing some of this with the "bevel and emboss" blending options.  @LostLord please link a photo of the "sand text writing".

Comment: I am not your friend - you're using *Photoshop!* (To all Photoshop Junkies: I'm *joking*, get it?)

Answer (score 7):

**Warning, image heavy**

I kind of understand your first question so that's all I'll attempt to answer for now, and please clarify if this is wrong, but here's how I see it:
You want to ONLY have the stroke on a circle, not the contents.

Two easy methods:

### Method 1:

`Circle marquee -> make your circle -> Select >> Modify >> Border -> Select amount -> Ok`
[image]

### Method 2:

(I prefer this method, it's cleaner)

`Make a circle --> open layer styles --> add a stroke --> ok`
Lower `Fill` to `0%`, then you are only left with your stroke.
[image]
[image]

**EDIT**
I think I understand Question 1 better now.

So, to isolate the stroke, and then use the strokes selection to mask, do the following:

`Layer -> Layer Style -> Create Layer`

This makes the layer style, into its own separate layer.
[image]
Now, select the orange circle (ctrl+click the layer's thumbnail)

Then, select the black layer...
[image]

And now hit "delete" -- this will erase the black circle's innards.
Now, simply select the remainder of the layer, and use that as your mask.

Comment: hi \ thanks 4 answers \ i edit my question for clarify \ i got my first question answer by method 1 - but where is Lower Fill to 0% in method 2?

Comment: what about the sand text ?(my #2 question)

Comment: If method 1 works fine for you, then method two doesn't matter. As, they are just different ways of doing the same thing. `Fill` is located where it's shown in the screenshot (It's outlined in red)

Comment: I am unsure by what you mean in question two as "sand text" -- again, I'll ask if you have an example to show.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. It stikes me as very odd that this common task takes so many steps in Photoshop while it is such a simple option (choosing a solid border and a different colour fill) in other tools like Adobe Fireworks and MS Paint.

Comment: It's not that odd. The other programs you mentioned focus more on basic shapes and their properties. Illustrator is another great example. Photoshop is just a much broader product. But I agree that some thing are a bit lengthy. And really if you're working with JUST shapes it will always be better to work in a vector format anyway.